# call EvalMath to parse math expression

Tags: php

I'm new in php. I want to evaluate math expression using [EvalMath](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html) class. I create new EvalMath using this code

```
require_once "evalmath.class.php";

$m = new EvalMath;

$result = $m->evaluate("2+2");

echo ($result);
```

instead of I get the result, I get the class content in my browser.

Did I miss something in my code?

Comment: This problem is solved. Add proper php tags (<?php [at the first line] and ?> [at the last line]) in evalmath.class.php.

Answer (score 1):

EvalMath class use

```
<?
```

at first line instead of

```
<?php
```

and have no closing php tag. Add proper php tag:

```
<?php
class EvalMath{
....
}
?>
```

It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid, but have you added PHP tags at the top of your file?

```
<?php
require_once "evalmath.class.php";
$m = new EvalMath;
$result = $m->evaluate("2+2");
echo ($result);
?>
```

Otherwise, I've tried your code and it works fine...

This project, FYI, looks promising.  EvalMath seems to be over 8 years old at this point.

https://github.com/Riimu/Expresso

Comment: I already added those tags, sorry for not mentioning that tags in my question. why I get different result? May be something wrong. But I don't know where to check.

Comment: I have found the problem. EvalMath class use <? at first line instead of <?php and have no closing php tag. I edit those class by adding proper php tag (<?php ... ?>), and it works. Now I can use those class for my project. Thank you very much.